# Why do the images in my HTML-created email signature blow up in Outlook?

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail, signature

I am very new to HTML as I am learning it for marketing purposes. The organization I work for asked me to create an email signature for them, which works fine in Gmail but not so well in Outlook. When replying to an email with the signature in Outlook, the images blow up to massive size instead of the size specified in the code. What is happening here?

This is what it is supposed to look like
[image]

This is what it looks like in an email reply in Outlook
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body
    style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:14px;margin:0px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;color:#71757e;line-height:15px;width:400px;height:200px">
    <table
       
           >
      <tr>
        <td
          class="table-wrapper"
          style="padding-top:40px;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td
                class="personal-image-wrapper"
                style="vertical-align:top;">
            <a href="https://www.boulangerinitiative.org/">
                <img
                  class="BI_Logo" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5b15c4b2af209664a48e3c58/a104e4b1-ea0d-4781-bb8d-a150a7db8866/BI_Logo+96.png?format=2500w"
                  style="width:110px;height:136px;border-radius:20px;border:0;"
                alt="BI Logo"/>
            </a>
              </td>
              <td
                class="info-wrapper"
                style="padding-left:5px;">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td
                      class="info-name"
                      style="font-family:trebuchet ms;color:#6a5f7f;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:4px;">
                      Firstname Lastname <br>
                        
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr
                    style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#71757e;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                    <td
                      class="info-profession"
                      style="font-family:trebuchet ms;color:#000000;">
                        they/them (<a href="https://uwm.edu/lgbtrc/support/gender-pronouns/">what's this</a>?)<br>
                        Role/Profession <br>
                        <a href="https://www.boulangerinitiative.org/"> boulangerinitiative.org</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr
                    style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                    <td
                      class="info-phone"
                      style="font-family:trebuchet ms;color:#000000;">
                      <strong>E:</strong> first@boulangerinitiative.org <br>
                        <strong>P:</strong> (555) 555-5555
                        
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td
                      class="info-social"
                      style="padding-top:8px;">
                      <table
                        style="font-size:14px;margin:0px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;">
                        <tr>
                          <td
                            class="IGLOGO">
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/boulangerinitiative/"
                              target="_blank">
                              <img
                                class="IGLOGO"
                                src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5b15c4b2af209664a48e3c58/1629850888402-99X4SHBR1RCH8RFJG5RQ/Instagram+.png?format=1500w"
                                style="margin-right:5px;width:20px;height:20px;border:0;"
                                   alt="Instagram"/>
                            </a>
                          </td>
                          <td
                            class="FBLOGO"
                            style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/boulangerinitiative"
                              target="_blank">
                              <img
                                class="FBLOGO"                           src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5b15c4b2af209664a48e3c58/1629850897830-B7AKEP9QL54J4MWVKMR1/Facebook+.png?format=1500w"
                                style="margin-right:5px;width:20px;height:20px;margin-right:5px;border:0;"
                                   alt="Facebook"/>
                            </a>
                          </td>
                            <td
                            class="Twitter"
                            style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;"
                          >
                            <a
                              href="https://www.twitter.com/boulangerinitia"
                              target="_blank"
                            >
                              <img
                                class="Twitter"
                                src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5b15c4b2af209664a48e3c58/1629850905140-MZE0OF2722UZS4YGI61F/Twitter+.png?format=1500w"
                                style="margin-right:5px;width:20px;height:20px;border:0;"
                                alt="Twitter"
                              />
                                <td
                            class="Tiktok"
                          >
                            <a
                              href="https://www.tiktok.com/@boulangerinitiative?lang=en"
                              target="_blank"
                            >
                              <img
                                class="Tiktok"
                                src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5b15c4b2af209664a48e3c58/1629850915135-ED2SBE8CHRE3TFZFMD1Q/Tiktok+.png?format=1500w"
                                style="margin-right:5px;width:20px;height:20px;border:0;"
                                   alt="Tiktok"
                              />
                            </a>
                          </td>
                                <td
                            class="Etsy"
                            style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;"
                          >
                            <a
                              href="https://www.etsy.com/shop/BoulangerInitiative?ref=simple-shop-header-name&listing_id=905209547"
                              target="_blank"
                            >
                              <img
                                class="Etsy"
                                src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5b15c4b2af209664a48e3c58/1629850922399-97YEKOUMT7D3YAZCSPIB/Etsy+.png?format=1500w"
                                style="margin-right:5px;width:20px;height:20px;border:0;"
                                   alt="Etsy"
                              />
                            </a>
                          </td>
                            </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add an `!important` after both the width and Height in the style.

Second you need to open a new message
Then add an emoji
[image]

Then press Ctrl + Shift + I for inspect
[image]

- Then paste all the html text on the emoji and then click somewhere around the text and make sure that the text is pasted correctly
- Now close the inspect page
- Then send the message to yourself and you will find that the image does not change its size.

I hope this helped you